# cannot read csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a python script that has a line `with open('gg.csv') as csv_file:`, and I have a csv file called gg.csv in the exact same directory as the python file, but when I run the script I am getting `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gg.csv'` - does anyone know of the solution?

Comment: Check the current working directory: `import os` and then `print(os.getcwd())`

Answer (score 2):

This is probably beacuse you run the script from different directoy.

For instance, if I have the following script at my Desktop:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

running the script from the Desktop I get:

```
~/Desktop » py3 SO.py                                         Sriker@Sriker-MBP
/Users/Sriker/Desktop
```

While from different directory I get:

```
~ » py3 Desktop/SO.py                                         Sriker@Sriker-MBP
/Users/Sriker
```

So you either run the script from the right directory, or build the path to `gg.csv` properly before trying to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Which os are you using?.
Try with providing full url to your file and see if it works

If you are using Windows, try renaming

```
open('gg.csv')
```

to

```
open('\gg.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(r'gg.csv') as csv_file:
```

this may work otherwise use

```
df=pd.read_csv("gg.csv")
```

if the csv is in row and column format.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**: You are running your script in another directory.

You are running it in another directory other than the main one. Basically, `"gg.csv"` in python has a relative path. For example, if I am in my home directory, (in Linux) this should correspond to the path of:

```
/home/<whatever username>/gg.csv
```

But say you are in your Desktop directory, in Linux, python interprets that as:

```
/home/<whatever username>/Desktop/gg.csv
```

Because you are running it in a different directory, Python thinks you are corresponding to the `gg.csv` there, not the `gg.csv` with the directory that has the script.

Thus, run it in the correct directory or set a *absolute* path that always links to the correct directory and path.